# Gradle Publish Plugin fails with "Execution failed for task ':signArchives'."

Tags: gradle, publish, gradle-plugin

I release my org's gradle plugin go the gradle repository using the Gradle Publish Plugin Repo. https://plugins.gradle.org/.

I created an account, created an API Key/Secret combo, and configured these properties in our gradle.properties file. I then call a `./gradlew publishPlugins`

This was working fine until sometime between January and May where we tried to release again. We now get the ``Execution failed for task ':signArchives'.``` Error. we have never needed to configure a signatory, but for some reason it's throwing this error now.

We've tried configuring the gradle.properties file in both our GRADLE_HOME and in the root project directory. We have also tried passing our properties as command line properties as such: `$ ./gradlew publishPlugins -Pgradle.publish.key=<key> -Pgradle.publish.secret=<secret>`. Our attempts have been to no avail.

Comment: Please provide your `build.gradle` and the exact stacktrace you are seeing by running the task with `--stacktrace` flag.

Comment: This is the [build.gradle](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.gradle/blob/master/build.gradle).

Comment: This is the [stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/jjvilleg/c08a6b589f760f6f49bfb52c7ba079cd).

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the links?